# How to filter out various titles with same keywords

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings that are similar as they contain the same keywords.

If more than one string has three or more of the same keywords, then I want only one string to be returned.

**Example:**

```
Ex Machina is an example of female artificial intelligence.
Ex Machina, why are most artificial intelligence represented as female?
Will Artificial Intelligence be represented females like in Ex Machina?
```

I would like to filter all strings for 3 keywords then I would like keep only one string.

Not sure if I can use regex alone or need JavaScript.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

How about simply looping over all the sentences and removing punctuation, and keeping the words in a map. Aggregate the count and then loop over the hash to find which words have occurred more than 3

```
function filter() {
    var sentences = [
        "Ex Machina is an example of female artificial intelligence.",
        "Ex Machina, why are most artificial intelligence represented as female?",
        "Will Artificial Intelligence be represented females like in Ex Machina?"
    ];

    var word_map = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
        var cur_sentence = sentences[i];
        cur_sentence = remove_punctuations(cur_sentence).toLowerCase().split(' ');

        cur_sentence.forEach(function(w) {
            if (word_map.hasOwnProperty(w)) {
                word_map[w] += 1;
            } else {
            word_map[w] = 1;
            }
        });
    }

    console.log(word_map);

}

function remove_punctuations(w) {
    return w.replace(/[\.?,]/g, '');
}
```